# Syntax of return statement in c++ when the function type is struct pair

Tags: c++, stl, std-pair

please help me understand the syntax of return statement when the function type is struct pair.

```
struct pair getMinMax(long long int arr[], long long int n) {
   
   long long int min, max;
   if( n == 1)
   {
       min = arr[0];
       max = arr[1];
       return {min,max};
   }
}
```

I am getting this error when I run:-

```
prog.c: In function getMinMax: prog.c:38:16: error: expected expression before { token return {min,max}; ^
```

P.S. Just For context I was attempting this problem on GFG
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/find-minimum-and-maximum-element-in-an-array4428/1#

Comment: Did you try `return pair{min,max};`?

Comment: `struct pair`  in c++ you don't need the `struct`.  Also there is a pair in the standard library so make sure you don't have `using namespace std;`

Comment: `struct pair`.  Is this a case of reading and learning from `C` material instead of C++ material?  Oh, and that website you linked to -- please do *not* use it to learn C++.

Comment: Also make sure that your function always returns a value. Currently the code only does so if n is 1. If you execute with `n` other than 1 you will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: How is `pair` defined?

Comment: `auto value = std::minmax(A, A + N); return {value.first, value.second};` -- That's the answer to the question you linked to.  I posted the answer, because I highly doubt you would learn that information from the linked website.  Or maybe simply: `return std::minmax(A, A + N);` depending on what `pair` is.

Comment: @drescherjm Not just ensuring a value is always returned, but actually selecting the min and max as well.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie [`std::minmax`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) doesn't accept iterator though.

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete.   You need to provide a definition of `pair`.   You also need to specify what C++ standard you are compiling for.   The `return {min,max}`  (returning from a function using uniform initialisation syntax) is only valid from C++11 AND depends on the definition of the struct.   Since you've omitted that relevant information, people can only guess what your problem is.

Comment: The file name "prog.c" (and "struct pair") suggests that you're actually programming in C, not in C++. (Also, you're not using either STL or `std::pair`...)

Comment: If `n` is 1, then there is no `arr[1]` unless `n` is being used in an unconventional manner.

Comment: @appleapple -- Yes, the correct solution would be: `auto value = std::minmax_element(A, A + N); return {*value.first, *value.second};`

Comment: Only use GFG once you are already experienced with C++, because GFG is egregiously and dreadfully poor.  Once you are an expert with C++, GFG makes for entertaining humor.

Comment: @Eljay -- GFG is a site where their explanation of how to solve the problems may be ok, but then when they post the coded solution, that's when things start to go awry with stuff like variable-length arrays, that `<bits` header, and whatever else that will make you into a horrible C++ programmer.  It seems to be that way for many of these sites -- the coded solution rarely, if ever, uses proper C++ and C++ idioms.

Answer (score -1):

Because `std::pair` is a template class with two type parameters and must be instansiated as `std::pair<type1,type2>`. When constructor arguments are available, those types can be deduced. Now that you use it as return type, you must explicitly specify them:

```
std::pair<std::int64_t, std::int64_t> getMinMax(long long int arr[], long long int n) ///...
```

Further more, your snippet should not compile even after the fix; because it does not return a value of same type outside the if branch. If all branches return values of same type, you can deduce the return type:

```
auto getMinMax(long long int arr[], long long int n) {
     ///...
     if (xxx)
         return std::pair{arr[0],arr[1]};
     return std::pair{0ll,0ll};
};
```

Comment: Guys, Thanks for all your answers!

As you all had mentioned, I was mistakenly executing for C instead of C++.

This is the correct syntax which got executed:-

pair<long long, long long> getMinMax(long long a[], int n) {
    long long min, max;
    pair <long long,long long> p;
    if( n == 1)
    {
        p.first = a[0];
        p.second = a[0];
        return p;
    }
}


This was my first question here, I am really overwhelming by all of your responses!